# Pulling Sequelize Info from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm pretty new to new sequelize but I'm trying to figure out how I can pull sequelize information from multiple tables (Place and Review tables) and render them on the same page. The Review table has a User Id and a Place Id. I've tried raw queries and different variations of the code below to no avail. What sort of syntax should I use in this case?

```
User.hasMany(Review);
Review.belongsTo(User);

User.hasMany(Place);
Place.belongsTo(User);

Place.hasMany(Review);
Review.belongsTo(Place);



app.get('/place/:category/:id', function(req, res){
  var id = req.params.id;
  Place.findAll({
    where : {id : id},
    include: [{
      model: [Review]
    }]
  }).then(function(reviews){
    res.render('singular', {reviews});
  });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your API route definition, I assume you're trying to display reviews for a place based on place ID.

So, to achieve this, you could model your table associations as

```
Places.hasMany(Reviews);
Users.hasMany(Reviews);

Review.belongsTo(Places);
Review.belongsTo(Users);
```

Now, based on this association, you could perform the query like this:

```
Places.findById(req.params.id, {
    include: [{
        model: Reviews,
        required: false,
        include: [{
            model: Users,
            required: false
        }]
    }]
}).then(function(place) {
    // The rest of your logic here...
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is a great solution to a problem that I had.